# Pyinstaller Config directory (linux)

Tags: linux, build, pyinstaller

**Short**:
When I run pyinstaller on linux, I see that it uses a fixed `Config` directory. I'd like to change that to a different directory.

**Elaborate**:
This job is part of build script. It is run in parallel on once machine. The first job is normal linux build. The second is coverage build. It fails when the build processes reach the pyinstaller jobs. My guess is that they both work on the same directory, which causes the failure. When I run the build processes serially they work fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that pyinstaller does not allow changing the config directory by parameter. But there is a workaround:

```
vim /opt/pyinstaller-2.1dev/PyInstaller/__init__.py
```

In the python file look for `CONFIGDIR =`

and change it for something unique. For example you can add process id to the name of the directory.